# Combinatorics understanding a counting chart

Tags: combinatorics

Good afternoon I am currently trying to self teach myself about combinatorics and this is the first time I have ever seen the following chart can anyone explain me why it’s set up in such a manner what does it mean?

I am dealing with grids (chess board) and guaranteeing  perfect Covers with dominos.

[image]

Any links, sources, explanations on how to read this type of chart would be helpful thank you.

Comment: They are simply indexing the colours instead of shading them. You could colour each cell with a $1$ red, each $2$ green, each $3$ yellow, and so on.

Comment: You've seen a checkerboard or chessboard, right?  The colors of the squares have particular meaning to their respective games (*in checkers/draughts, the pieces are all placed on spaces of the same color for instance and move diagonally*).  Well... imagine a game where the board has more than just two colors and said colors are lined up diagonally.

Comment: If you need an actual image or problem which uses more than two colors to be able to understand it... see for instance [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055087/chess-board-combinatorics/) where we colored a chessboard rather than with the traditional two colors instead with *three* colors in order to prove a point.

Comment: @JMoravitz, and Théophile, thank you for not disregarding this as trivial trash I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help! Mathematicians have a fairly abstract understanding of what colours are... :)